# SOAP error when trying to access data and template from Designer

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, web-services, master-page

I get the following error message when trying to view a msater page or try to view data from SharePoint Designer:

> soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> Value does not
> fall within the expected range.

What do I do to fix this error?

My SharePoint webservices seems to be running in IIS:
[image: IIS Screen shot]

I am running SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured the configuring alternate access mapping as in Internet Zone ? If not, then configure it and try connecting using SharePoint Designer 2010 again.